# change language of bibtex entry

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

How can I change the language that the entries in the table of reference appear. For example in the case of multiple authors, I see author1 AND author2. I would like to transform `and -> und` as german is the language I am writing (same for `edition-> Auflage`).

.LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    text \cite{hawking}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

This is the sample.bib file

```
@book{hawking,
          title     = "A Brief History of Time: From the {B}ig {B}ang to Black Holes",
          author    = "Stephen Hawking and Stephen Spielberg",
          year      = 1988,
          publisher = "Bantam",
          address   = "London",
          edition=3
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using apalike-german as bibliography style should work for you

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    text \cite{hawking}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{apalike-german}
    \bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SXlDid you load `babel` (or `polyglossia`) with the relevant option?

Comment: Are you suggesting to add a line like `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` ? this does not look to be necessary in this MWE.

Comment: That's the way biblatex knows which language to use. By default, it's american english. You alse can use the `langid` field if you want it to depend on the language of the reference.

Comment: @Bernard Despite the `biblatex` tag (which I just removed to avoid confusion) the OP is actually using standard BibTeX. Many BibTeX styles like `apalike` have their language hard-coded and do not respond to `babel` or `polyglossia` language changes.

Comment: I see. The U.P. should probably be advised to use `biblatex-apa`, unless he/she has serious reasons not to.

Comment: One thing to recall is that `apalike` is really only "like APA". If one needs real APA style, one should use `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa`. If one just wants author-year citations, one can use the standard `style=authoryear,`.